# Change the page when the animation is completed

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I need change the page of my App of Windows Phone when the animation finish, but my code doesn't do it, it only change the page.

```
  private void e(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
      video.Begin();
      NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Page1.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
  }
```

Them, I try with:

```
  private void e(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
      video.Begin();
      video.Completed += new EventHandler(finish);
  }

  private void finish()
  {
      NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Page1.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
  }
```

But new EventHadler give me a problem:

```
 delegate System.EventHandler

 Representa el método que controlara eventos que no tienen datos de evento.

 Error: 
 Ninguna sobrecarga correspondiente a 'finish' coincide con el 'System.EventHadler' delegado
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The signature of your `finish` method is wrong. You have to change it to:

```
private void finish(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Page1.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
}
```